# Code using up 75-85% of my Pi3 CPU

Tags: python, temperature

Sorry if this has an obvious answer to some of you out there, I am however pretty new to python and still in the learning phase.

My code, posted below, runs laggy (slower than the two sleep commands), however my code surely should not be using up 75 to 85% of my cpu? I think I must have done something wrong and was wondering if anyone could take a look at it for me please?

Running on a Raspberry Pi 3, with a Temperature sensor, relay and RGB LED.
I view my raspberry pi through VNC.

I would be very grateful for the help.

```
'''
RASPBERRY PI TEMPERATURE CONTROLL FOR BEER FRIDGE
'''

import os
import glob
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import *

#initialise datetime counter
d0 = datetime(2017,1,1,0,0,0)
d1 = datetime.now()
d2 = int((d1-d0).seconds)
d2 = int(d2/60)
d3 = d2 + 1

#set graph style
style.use("ggplot")

#Set gpio's
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)#RED
GPIO.setup(22,GPIO.OUT)#GREEN
GPIO.setup(27,GPIO.OUT)#BLUE
GPIO.setup(5,GPIO.OUT)#RELAY
GPIO.output(5,GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(17,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(22,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(27,GPIO.LOW)

#grab temp probe information
os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'


# Read temperature from device

def read_temp_raw():
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines

def read_temp():
    lines=read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.1)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000
        #temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
        return temp_c#, temp_f

def increase():  #increase button press
    global desiredtemp
    desiredtemp += 0.5
    tmpstr.set("%s" % desiredtemp)

def decrease():  #Decrease button press
    global desiredtemp
    desiredtemp -= 0.5
    tmpstr.set("%s" % desiredtemp)

temp = read_temp()
desiredtemp = 5
deg = u'\xb0'#utf code for degree
relay = "N/A"

#Tkinter start
root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Beer Temp") #Name the title bar

#make 5 frames for text and buttons and graph
topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack(side=TOP)

middleFrame = Frame(root)
middleFrame.pack()

midlowFrame = Frame(root)
midlowFrame.pack()

bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack()

bottombottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottombottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

#Variables for tkinter
tmpstr = StringVar(value="%s" % desiredtemp)
crtmpstr = StringVar(value="%s" % temp)
relaystatus = StringVar(value="%s" % relay)

#Set labels
label1 = Label(topFrame, text="Desired Temp = ", fg="black")
label2 = Label(middleFrame, text="Actual Temp = ", fg="black")
label3 = Label(topFrame, textvariable=tmpstr, fg="black")
label4 = Label(midlowFrame, text="Relay = ", fg="purple")
label5 = Label(midlowFrame, textvariable=relaystatus, fg="purple")
label6 = Label(middleFrame, textvariable=crtmpstr, fg="black")

#use to put labels on screen
label1.pack(side=LEFT)
label2.pack(side=LEFT)
label3.pack(side=LEFT)
label4.pack(side=LEFT)
label5.pack(side=LEFT)
label6.pack(side=LEFT)

#Set buttons
button1 = Button(bottomFrame, text="Increase (0.5"+ deg +"C)", fg="darkgreen", command=increase)
button2 = Button(bottomFrame, text="Decrease (0.5"+ deg +"C)", fg="red", command=decrease)

#use to put buttons on screen
button1.pack(side=LEFT)
button2.pack(side=LEFT)

#Graph at bottom of window
f1 = Figure(figsize=(5,3), dpi =100)
a = f1.add_subplot(111)
xList = list(range(0,61))
yList = [0]*61
a.plot(xList, yList)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f1, bottombottomFrame)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

#animating the graph (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQ7QP5rPvjU)
def animate(i):
    a.clear()
    a.plot(xList,yList)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f1, animate, interval=1000)

# Continuous print loop
while True:
    while (d3>d2):
        if(read_temp()>=desiredtemp):
            GPIO.output(17,GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(5,GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(22,GPIO.LOW)
            crtmpstr.set("%s" % read_temp())
            relay="ON"
            relaystatus.set("%s" % relay)
        else:
            GPIO.output(17,GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(5,GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(22,GPIO.HIGH)
            crtmpstr.set("%s" % read_temp())
            relay="OFF"
            relaystatus.set("%s" % relay)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        d1 = datetime.now()
        d2 = int((d1-d0).seconds)
        d2 = int(d2/60)
        d4 = int((d1-d0).seconds)
        root.update()
    d3 = d2 + 1
    '''update counter to increase by one minute, this should not lose
    time as it reads the whole minute then adds one. even if the counter
    loses seconds every cycle it will still be close to the start of the
    minute/within the minute.'''
    yList.pop(0)
    yList.append(read_temp())

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you all for your suggestions, however I have found the source of the slow code using up all of my CPU, it is the graph section. When I comment out this section of code it uses barely any of my CPU

```
#Graph at bottom of window
f1 = Figure(figsize=(5,3), dpi =100)
a = f1.add_subplot(111)
xList = list(range(0,61))
yList = [0]*61
a.plot(xList, yList)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f1, bottombottomFrame)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

#animating the graph (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQ7QP5rPvjU)
def animate(i):
    a.clear()
    a.plot(xList,yList)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f1, animate, interval=1000)
```

Comment: Unless the code is massive add it to your question.

Comment: done, my apologies.

Comment: What happens if you add a time.sleep(0.1) after the while True?

Comment: endless loops make me nervous.. Best suggestion here is to comment out parts of the code until you see the decline in CPU usage. Then depending on what that "code" does is going to need optimisation or probably something else. This is just the normal part of software devs life, called debugging. Good luck

Comment: I am not a regular Python programmer, but **ANY** code which continuously runs a loop is going to burn processor resources (uselessly). You can include sleep, but a better solution is a timer based interrupt, or wait for event. The **FIRST** step is to actually define the project requirements. I doubt you need to check temperature more often then every 10 minutes.

Comment: I agree with @Milliways.  The biggest reason for it to use so much CPU is because it is always running.  Your delays are so small as to be nearly nonexistant.  I run systems like this and agree that emperatures can be taken less frequently.  As long as that is the only purpose of the program it should give the CPU a rest periodically.  Also, you are importing a massive library load.  Simple calls in your program are invoking large amounts of processing.  Perhaps you can find simpler ways to handle this without creating such a large executing codebase.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions, however I have found the source of the slow code using up all of my CPU, it is the graph section. you can see in my update above. when this is commented out my cpu usage is under 5%

Answer (score 1):

As you are continuously loopping in your script, the pi is reading the temperature, updating the window and animating the graph every time it completes a loop. This uses the CPU to redraw the window and then animate the graph, this uses a considerable amount of resources and considering the low amount available on your pi this is why you have a high cpu use all the time.

The delay you have included is going to have barely any effect on the script from using less resources. As this is being used in a fridge the temperature isn't going to vary that much to be worth measuring in a short space of time (as mentioned by SDsolar), so putting a long delay into the code isn't really going to have that much of an effect on the temperature accuracy, if anything it will remove any random fluctuations within the fridge.

You can also only import the functions you require from the libaries you have imported, this will reduce the amount of stuff in RAM and allow the pi to work faster.